# Ghost orders in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I am on Magento ver. 2.4.2 EE

I have reported that rising cases of orders appearing in Stripe but not in Magento. Most seem to be paid with Apple Pay.

I have looked in admin for a customer, the order has been placed by that customer but order not found in grid or customer's order tab.

I am looking for some ideas, what to check (test cases)
in order to detect issue & fix it then.

Comment: Guys do let me know if you find question is unclear, any thoughts on answer to this question greatly appreciated.

Comment: any thoughts on this guys ?

Comment: Try to check your webhook or IPN working or not?

Comment: In my stripe dashboard i can see order placed associated with an customer email id but in magento i am not

Comment: What you think, where i can cross check ?

Comment: Which extension are you used for the stripe payment method?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/plugins/magento/install Its official

Comment: Please check in sales_order table order data saved or not. If saved then it may be the grid issue.

Comment: Issue is in live so not able to access its db

Comment: Any other way to confim this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you can take to investigate the issue:

- Check the Magento order logs: Check the Magento order logs to see if there are any errors or issues related to the missing orders. You can find the logs in the var/log directory of your Magento installation.
- Check the Stripe dashboard: Check the Stripe dashboard to see if the orders were successfully processed and paid for. If they were, then the issue may be related to the integration between Stripe and Magento.
- Check the integration between Stripe and Magento: Make sure that the integration between Stripe and Magento is properly configured and up-to-date. You can do this by checking the configuration settings in the Magento admin panel and ensuring that you have the latest version of the Stripe payment module installed.
- Check the Apple Pay configuration: If the missing orders were paid for using Apple Pay, then check the Apple Pay configuration settings in your Magento installation to ensure that they are properly configured.
- Test the checkout process: Try placing a test order using Apple Pay and see if it appears in both Stripe and Magento. This will help you determine if the issue is related to a specific payment method or the checkout process in general.
- Contact support: If you are still unable to find the issue, contact Stripe and Magento support teams for further assistance. They may be able to provide additional insights or help you troubleshoot the issue.